# ReactJs increment translateX() on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given :

```js
function App() {
    var xPos = 0;
    const [style, setStyle] = React.useState({transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)`});
  
    const onClick =(direction) => {
       (direction === "left") ? xPos -= 100 : xPos += 100;
       setStyle({transform: `translateX(${xPos}px)`});
           console.log(xPos)
        }

    return (
          <div className="main_container">
             <button className="left_button" onClick={() => onClick("left")}>slide left</button>
             <div className="forecast_slider" >
                <div className="forecast_container" style={style} > 
                   {forecastBuilder()}
                </div>
             </div>
             <button className="right_button" onClick={() => onClick("right")}>slide right</button>
          </div>
       )
   }

const forecastBuilder = () => {
const cell = [];
  for(var i = 1 ; i < 8 ; i++){
    cell.push(
        <div className={i}>
        {i}
        <img src="https://imgs.michaels.com/MAM/assets/1/5E3C12034D34434F8A9BAAFDDF0F8E1B/img/0E9397ED92304202B4A25D7387A74515/M10118706_2.jpg" width="100" height="80" border="1px solid black" />
        <br></br>
        <span>day {i}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return cell;
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.main_container {
  display:flex;
}
.forecast_container { 
    display: flex;
    width: 510px;
    height: 130px;
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    
    transition: transform 250ms;
  }
  .forecast_slider {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
  
     overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <div id="app"></div>
```

with [JSFiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/ebzqm06v/92/) ,

I want to make the `translateX()` animation increment and decrement upon respective button click. Currently, I suspect that when I call `setStyle()` hook, the component gets rerendered such that the line

```
var xPos=0;
```

is read again. I was not able to find a way to increment or decrement in another way (without beforehand assigning the value of `0` such that `style = {style}` on the first render ignores the parameter).

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: create another `useState` hook to save `xPos` value due renders. this will ensure you have a non zero value due renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `xPos` is going to be set as `0` on every render, so you are not saving it's new value, it gets reset on every render.

You should store the `xPos` in the state as well.

```
const [xPos, setXpos] = useState(0)
```

and then increment / decrement in the function itself:

```
    const onClick = (direction) => {
    (direction === "left") ? setXpos(x => x - 100) : setXpos(x => x + 100)
}
```

This should work

Comment: Damnit, so simple. Why didn't I think of that :p. Thank you.